# Dropwdown nav / sorting dd in same aligment as button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm playing with dropdown menus in CSS and I run into some troubles.
I wish to make dropdown boxes be in same line as button you click to open dd.
This is CSS code:

```
/* for all */
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* style in first box */
#a1 {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 6em;
    font-family: Shrikhand;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px #000000;
}

/* style in second box */
#a2 {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    height: 300px;
}

#mbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.li {
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list- style: none;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.li2 {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: none;
    width: 130.981px;
}

.dd {
    width: 130.981px;
}

    .dd:hover .li2 {
        display: block;
    }
```

Here is HTML code:

```
<div id="a2">
    <div id="mbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="li">index</li>
            <li class="li">gallery</li>
            <li class="li dd">
                dropdown
                <ul>
                    <li class="li2">dropdown1</li>
                    <li class="li2">dropdown2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="li">contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/MonkeyCode/pen/RZqbVN)

Anyway if you click on dropdown button you will see that dropdown nav is out of aligment with dropdown button.

Comment: You should add also the HTML code in the question

Comment: And please work on your treatment of ``;``, whitespaces and indentation/code cleanness in general. Not ment offensively.

Comment: Hi! I have added html. Sorry i get cofused with code system here sometimes it works sometimes it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to play it with positions: [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzVvVz)

short answer is :

```
.dd {
 position: relative;
}

.dd ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thx but i would like something more elegant, playign with relative apsbolute will mess my responsivnes?

Comment: could you please elaborate the type of elegency :D ? how would it break the responsivness btw?

Comment: Sorry it was my wrong assumption that it will break responsivnes because of my bad expiriance with apsolute positioning in the past! I forgot to write you, it works flawleslly thank you very much

Comment: never mind. you can easily handle positioning with different media queries at any breakpoint.